# loop through 2 items using g:each in grails

Tags: grails, gsp

Can I loop through more than 1 item in g:each tag in grails? I want to simultaneously loop through 2 items of same length and then display the response.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, you can. 
You can use `status` to know which loop it is and which element to grab.

```
<g:each in="${firstList}" status="i" var="elem">                
   <td>${secondList[i].attribute}</td> //you can access 2nd list elements like this
   <td>${elem.attribute}</td> //you can access first list elements like this
</g:each>
```